# Break out of select loop?

Tags: select, concurrency, go, goroutine

I'm trying to use a `select` in a loop to receive either a message or a timeout signal. If the timeout signal is received, the loop should abort:

```
package main
import ("fmt"; "time")
func main() {
    done := time.After(1*time.Millisecond)
    numbers := make(chan int)
    go func() {for n:=0;; {numbers <- n; n++}}()
    for {
        select {
            case <-done:
                break
            case num := <- numbers:
                fmt.Println(num)
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be stopping:

```
$ go run a.go
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
[...]
3824
3825
[...]
```

Why? Am I using `time.After` wrong?

Comment: If you keep waiting for something that has already happened, you will never timeout.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Go [spec says](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements):

> A "break" statement terminates execution of the innermost "for",
>   "switch", or "select" statement within the same function.

In your example you're just breaking out of the select statement. If you replace `break` with a `return` statement you will see that it's working.

Comment: But why does `break` do anything in a `select`/`switch`? I thought they already break out by default and that's why there's the `fallthrough` keyword?

Comment: A `select` statement is not a `switch` statement. `fallthrough` only applies to `switch` statements, see [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements)

Comment: This might be confusing because people sometimes speak of "falling through" in a select statement but that is something entirely different. It's when you have a default clause that makes the select statement non-blocking.

Comment: And you might want to use a break statement when you want to exit a larger case-block. (Haha, I hope I didn't cause more confusion...)

Comment: You could exit the case clause by using `if`, or `goto`, or another `switch`, but ok? So I guess I need to use a labeled break like in Martin's answer every time I have a process that receives multiple messages from more than one channel?

Comment: Typically you have a function that listens to these multiple channels that you can then simply exit by calling return. Doing more logic after the for-select pattern makes it harder to reason about your code. If you need to cleanup things before "returning" you should use the `defer` statement. That's the clean method, of course you can use labels if you prefer or have to use that. I personally never use them.

Comment: But what if one of the channels is some data and the other channel sends a message like "switch mode", and I want to do another select after that in the new mode?

Comment: That sounds like a classical state machine. Instead of handling two modes (or states) in the same function you would create a mechanism outside of this function that listens to mode changes and then exchanges the handlers/functions that listen to the data. But this is now a different problem than your original question and example code, right?

Comment: Not really, I figured out I can fix it with `goto` but I didn't realize I could use labelled `break` instead. I didn't think of `return` because my intent was to do more after the loop. What if I only have two or three "modes" or "states"? Then would the overhead of constructing a state machine still be worth it?

Comment: Yes, go for it. Do the nice thing :-) Because when changing modes you also want to change "back" to a mode "before", yes? Then you will be using break with labels to goto another select statement. You will at this point essentially use goto to switch modes of something that resembles a state machine. Can you do it with goto or labeled breaks? Of course, no question. But it is also the road to spaghetti code. Why don't you give it a try? No time? Or maybe even better, you find a solution where you don't need goto nor a state machine! Best, p

Comment: Instead of the return, use a label before the `for` and break to that label.

Answer (score 31):

The "Go" way for that kind of situations is to use labels and break on the label, for example:

```
L:
    for {
        select {
            case <-done:
                break L
            case num := <- numbers:
                fmt.Println(num)
        }
    }
```

Ref:

- http://www.goinggo.net/2013/11/label-breaks-in-go.html
- http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Break_statements

Answer (score 13):

In your example code, a `return` seems appropriate as Pat says, but for future reference you can use labels:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    done := time.After(1 * time.Millisecond)
    numbers := make(chan int)

    // Send to channel
    go func() {
        for n := 0; ; {
            numbers <- n
            n++
        }
    }()

readChannel:
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            break readChannel
        case num := <-numbers:
            fmt.Println(num)
        }
    }

    // Additional logic...
    fmt.Println("Howdy")
}
```

Comment: I've added a minus because labels for loops are a thing that hurts the readability of the code more than anything else I know including global variables in my opinion. I think they should be avoided at any cost.

Comment: @DmitryVerhoturov This is cargo cult nonsense. Go included labels and goto for a reason (and excluded many other more "popular" features instead). If you need to break out of a loop from inside a select statement using a label is a reasonable solution. It's not like you even provided an alternative (which I suppose would be to set a local variable in the select and check it right outside to perform the break).

Comment: A more readable alternative is just around a corner, it's [separating a loop to separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879632/961092) with `return`s inside it. Return is way more readable than `break label`. If it's a "cargo cult", please provide an example from real code where a separate function with the `return` will become easier to comprehend after removing the function and introducing a label: I can't think of one in any Go code I've seen so far, and on the opposite, I saw many places which could be improved by introducing a function.

Answer (score 9):

I have the following solution, by using a anonymous function.

```
    func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            if token := c.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
                fmt.Println("connect err:", token.Error())
            } else {
                fmt.Println("breaking")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    }()
```

Answer (score 9):

How about using some control variable to skip the loop? It's kind of hard or not so easy to understand with breaking label sometimes.

```
package main
import ("fmt"; "time")
func main() {
    done := time.After(1*time.Millisecond)
    numbers := make(chan int)
    go func() {for n:=0;; {numbers <- n; n++}}()
    completed := false
    for !completed {
        select {
            case <-done:
                completed = true
                // no break needed here
            case num := <- numbers:
                fmt.Println(num)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so simple and elegant

Comment: this works well and simple to read and understand